# What exactly is the toggle option for Pages in Settings > [your name] > Pages for? It apparently does not good

Tags: ipad, icloud, pages

If you have the iCloud Drive turned on, the Pages files get stored on iCloud Drive and if it is off, they are stored locally. This is decided on the option set in Settings > Pages and there you select where to save. What exactly is the toggle option for Pages in Settings > [your name] > Pages for? (It's right below the iCloud Drive toggle)

This is the toggle option I'm talking about (also, personal info has been removed, in case the picture looks weird) :

[image]

Comment: Hi, why did you repost your question? You did the same thing to the last question you had?

Comment: @grg Yes. This is just to ensure that the question is on the top for sometime again. It didn't get an answer yesterday and given the fact this is no interesting/useful question, I don't expect an answer very fast. Is it against the rules of Stack? (I've deleted the previous post)

Comment: You can bump a question by editing it with a meaningful edit (like you did to the previous question). Repetitive editing is against the rules, and reposting questions will get you closer to an automated question suspension by the system. Questions aren’t lost just because they’re not on the front page, there’s no need to bump a question for at least a few days.

Comment: @grg Sure, I'll take that into account.

Comment: Instead of reposting/bumping please also consider the points listed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. This will make it easier for people to actually read your question and provide answers.

Comment: Specifically your post here is both hard to understand and seems to lack focus. "If you have the Drive turned on" -> which drive, where/how, how does this relate to the question. The toggle option you ask about: could you add a screenshot so people don't have to guess whether they look at the same thing as you do?

Comment: Also (sic), the part starting with "Also" seems to be a second question (if it's a question at all) so to focus your question on the toggle issue it may not even be important here.

Comment: @nohillside I have added a picture so it is more understandable. I hope that makes it clear?